# How to model Many to Many Relationship as Class in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, class

I want to model my database tables as classes. In my database, I have many to many relationship as below, and I want to get ideas how to model it correctly.

[image: table relationship].

These are the classes that I have tried to create for these three tables.

```java
class Product {
    ......
    private List<Price> priceList;
    ......
}
```

```java
class Price{
    .....
    private List<Product> products;
    .....
}
```

I think this way can help me model those tables correctly, but I lost the fields - `price_list.amount`.

Comment: Introduce a third class `PriceList` that references a `Price`, a `Product` and has a member `amount`.

Comment: Do you really want to model the whole tables as a single class? An object in Java usually represents a single entry in a database table, not the table itself with all the entries. What exactly do you want to model?

Comment: Oh, thanks @LutzHorn. I just think if there is another way that can wrap these three tables into two tables.

Comment: No, I don't @deHaar. What I know is that if the composite table has only two foreign keys, I can model these three tables into two class. And for this question, I just want more ideas that can help me model correctly.

Comment: You could model those three tables into two classes, but that would barely reflect your database structure. In my opinion, you should create three classes: `Product`, `Price` and `ProductPrice` or `ProductHasPrice` for example. The latter just represents this composite key table. If you have a proper business layer in your project architecture, you can use a `Map<Product, Price>` there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two classes, simply join the Price List table with either Price or Product. For example:

```
public class PricePoint
{
    private int priceId;
    private int priceListId;
    private String description;
    private Date createdOn;
    private boolean status;
    private int amount;
    private List<Product> products;
}

public class Product
{
    private List<PricePoint> pricePoints;
    //...
}
```